# org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: Apr near line 1, column 81

Tags: hibernate, date

I'm trying to query a list of data from the database witch depend on the date.

Here is my code:

```
@Override
public List<CoursChange> listeTauxChange(Date datJourCchn) {

    Query q = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery(
            "from CoursChange  c where c.datJourCchn="+datJourCchn);
    return q.list();

}
```

The error is:

> org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: Apr near line 1, column 81 [from com.gtec.GestionChangeDevise.entity.CoursChange  c where c.datJourCchn=Mon Apr 18 00:00:00 WAT 2016]

How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all never parametrize query by concatenating it with stringified parameter values. Use [named](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnbrg.html#bnbrh) or [positioned](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnbrg.html#bnbri) parameter declaration in query string and then set parameter values to Query object.

```
Query q = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery(
        "from CoursChange  c where c.datJourCchn=:DAT_JOUR_CCHN");
q.setParameter("DAT_JOUR_CCHN", datJourCchn, TemporalType.DATE)
return q.list();
```

Comment: It is worse to mention that `Apr` is a result of `datJourCchn.toString()`. `TemporalType.DATE` is not necessary as I think.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I'll try it and tell u :)

Comment: @v.ladynev Third argument `TemporalType` is sometimes not neccessary and sometimes very very important. With informations only from given question no one can decide if it is neccessary or important in this case.

Comment: it works Sir ; thank you, But without mentioning TemporalType.DATE :)

Answer (score -1):

you miss `"` to wrap datJourCchn

```
"from CoursChange  c where c.datJourCchn = \"" + datJourCchn + "\""
```

column 81 of [from com.gtec.GestionChangeDevise.entity.CoursChange c where c.datJourCchn=Mon Apr 18 00:00:00 WAT 2016] is a space, which causes wrong query string.

Comment: thnkx for responding me;
but I couldn't understand the utility of (\)

Comment: the error now is:

 unexpected char: '"' [from com.gtec.GestionChangeDevise.entity.CoursChange  c where c.datJourCchn = "null"]

Comment: "null" is not `java.util.Date`, you should check that datJourCchn is passing correctly or not first, and then query string. It should looks like `from com.gtec.GestionChangeDevise.entity.CoursChange c where c.datJourCchn="Mon Apr 18 00:00:00 WAT 2016"`